# Android SharedViewModels vs Clean Architecture repositories

Tags: android, android-fragments, repository-pattern, android-viewmodel, clean-architecture

Let's say I have a flow of screens A, B, C, D where user constructs along the screens some data to perform a final operation with them on D, but be able to go back to previous screens to edit some of the data. The data doesn't need to be cached or persisted other than in this flow of screens.

As all of the screens are fragments, one approach is to have the hosting activity use a shared ViewModel where all of the fragments will be able to link the same instance of viewmodel and thus edit the same data object, still maintaining specific presentation logic on their own fragment view model. In this way, each fragment's viewmodel will have a reference to the activity shared view model.

```
                |    AViewModel    | AFragment
SharedViewmodel |    BViewModel    | BFragment
                |    CViewModel    | CFragment
                |    DViewModel    | DFragment
```

However, the project uses Clean architecture with Use cases and Repositories to access db data and remote data and operations.

In that case, shouldn't the data instead be an in-memory datasource for the repository and disregard completely the sharedviewmodel strategy, so that each fragment viewmodel will obtain and save the information from use cases and repositories?

```
                   |           |          | AViewModel | AFragment
inMemoryDataSource | Repostory | UseCases | BViewModel | BFragment
                   |           |          | CViewModel | CFragment
                   |           |          | DViewModel | DFragment
```

If so, by using Clean Architecture is it correct to avoid the use of shared viewmodels between fragments? i.e. is there a situation where a sharedViewModel be useful?